# Handle multiple JSON formats in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have created these typealias in my project

```
typealias JSON = [String: AnyObject]
typealias JSONArray = [JSON]
```

I'm testing an JSON API Client using [JSONPlaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/) and getting two different JSON responses.

Response 1 (JSON)

```
{
 userId: 1,
 id: 1,
 title: "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
 body: "quia et suscipit suscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum reprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam nostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
}
```

Response 2 (Array of JSON)

```
[
 {
  userId: 1,
  id: 1,
  title: "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
  body: "quia et suscipit suscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum reprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam nostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
 },
 {
  userId: 1,
  id: 2,
  title: "qui est esse",
  body: "est rerum tempore vitae sequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque fugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis qui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
 },
 ...
]
```

In order to create my code as generic as possible, I'm using a protocol approach. Everything works fine but I have a small issue parsing the json response.

```
// JSONResource is a protocol
extension JSONResource {

 func handleResponse(_ data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> WebServiceResult<Response> {

 let parsedData = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)

    do {
      if let json = parsedData as? JSON {
        let parsedResponse = try Response(json: json)
        return .success(parsedResponse)
      }

      if let jsonArray = parsedData as? JSONArray {
        let parsedResponse = try Response(jsonArray: jsonArray)
        return .success(parsedResponse)
      }

    } catch let error as NSError {
      return .failure(error)
    }
 }
}
```

The Response is created using a protocol too

```
protocol JSONServiceResponse: WebServiceResponse {
  init(json: JSON) throws
  init(jsonArray: JSONArray) throws
}
```

My problem is my code seems redundant because I have to handle JSON an JSONArray types but I'll only know that when I'm creating the type who implements the protocol.

Is there a different way to handle the JSON and JSONArray responses from the server in order to use a unique `init(json: JSON)` ?

Thanks

Comment: Personal choice, but I'd rename your `typealias JSON` into `typealias JSONDict`, because it doesn't make sense since they are both JSON valid.

Comment: @Larme Good idea :) Thanks

Comment: Also, because your sample doesn't reflect all your needs, but what about always returning (in the closure) an array? In pseudo code, `let jsonArray =. parsedData; if json as? JSONDict{ jsonArray = [json]; } let parsedResponse = try Response(jsonArray: jsonArray)`